# How to implement EJB timer service in Wildfly AS 8 for a datasource

Tags: timer, persistence, ejb-3.1, wildfly-8

I am migrating the EAR application from JBoss AS 6 to Wildfly AS 8.2.0. While doing, I am facing a concern on implementing `EJB timer service` in Wildfly AS for the datasource `TestSybaseDB` defined in `standalone-full-ha.xml`.

FYI that below are the files related to JBoss AS 6 related to EJB3 timer service implementation for the datasource `TestSybaseDB`. In below files of JBoss 6 AS, datasource name is defined and I believe these changes are enough for implementation of EJB timer service in JBoss 6 AS for a database.

**persistence.xml**

```
path: ${JBOSS_HOME}\common\deploy\jboss-ejb3-timerservice-mk2.jar\META-INF\persistence.xml

<jta-data-source>java:/TestSybaseDB</jta-data-source>
```

**ejb2-timer-service.xml**

```
path: ${JBOSS_HOME}\server\default\deploy\ejb2-timer-service.xml

<depends>jboss.jdbc:datasource=TestSybaseDB,service=metadata</depends>
<depends optional-attribute-name="DataSource">jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=TestSybaseDB</depends>
```

But to implement in Wildfly AS, I had converted the content of `timer-sql.properties` according to Sybase DB.

**timer-sql.properties**

```
path: ${JBOSS_HOME}\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\ejb3\main\timers\timer-sql.properties

create-table=CREATE TABLE JBOSS_EJB_TIMER (ID VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, TIMED_OBJECT_ID VARCHAR NOT NULL, INITIAL_DATE DATETIME, REPEAT_INTERVAL BIGINT, NEXT_DATE DATETIME, PREVIOUS_RUN DATETIME, PRIMARY_KEY VARCHAR, INFO VARCHAR, TIMER_STATE VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_SECOND VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MINUTE VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_HOUR VARCHAR,SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_WEEK VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_MONTH VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MONTH VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_YEAR VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_START_DATE VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_END_DATE VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_TIMEZONE VARCHAR, AUTO_TIMER SMALLINT, TIMEOUT_METHOD_NAME VARCHAR, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DECLARING_CLASS VARCHAR, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DESCRIPTOR VARCHAR, CALENDAR_TIMER SMALLINT, PARTITION_COL VARCHAR NOT NULL);
create-timer=INSERT INTO JBOSS_EJB_TIMER (ID, TIMED_OBJECT_ID, INITIAL_DATE, REPEAT_INTERVAL, NEXT_DATE, PREVIOUS_RUN, PRIMARY_KEY, INFO, TIMER_STATE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_SECOND, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MINUTE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_HOUR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_WEEK, SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_MONTH, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MONTH, SCHEDULE_EXPR_YEAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_START_DATE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_END_DATE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_TIMEZONE, AUTO_TIMER, TIMEOUT_METHOD_NAME, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DECLARING_CLASS, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DESCRIPTOR, CALENDAR_TIMER, PARTITION_COL) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25);
update-timer=UPDATE JBOSS_EJB_TIMER SET NEXT_DATE=$1, PREVIOUS_RUN=$2, TIMER_STATE=$3 WHERE TIMED_OBJECT_ID=$4 and ID=$5 AND PARTITION_COL=$6;
delete-timer=DELETE FROM JBOSS_EJB_TIMER WHERE TIMED_OBJECT_ID=$1 and ID=$2 AND PARTITION_COL=$3;
load-all-timers=SELECT ID, TIMED_OBJECT_ID, INITIAL_DATE, REPEAT_INTERVAL, NEXT_DATE, PREVIOUS_RUN, PRIMARY_KEY, INFO, TIMER_STATE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_SECOND, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MINUTE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_HOUR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_WEEK, SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_MONTH, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MONTH, SCHEDULE_EXPR_YEAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_START_DATE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_END_DATE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_TIMEZONE, AUTO_TIMER, TIMEOUT_METHOD_NAME, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DECLARING_CLASS, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DESCRIPTOR, CALENDAR_TIMER FROM JBOSS_EJB_TIMER WHERE TIMED_OBJECT_ID=$1 AND PARTITION_COL=$2;
load-timer=SELECT ID, TIMED_OBJECT_ID, INITIAL_DATE, REPEAT_INTERVAL, NEXT_DATE, PREVIOUS_RUN, PRIMARY_KEY, INFO, TIMER_STATE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_SECOND, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MINUTE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_HOUR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_WEEK, SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_MONTH, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MONTH, SCHEDULE_EXPR_YEAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_START_DATE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_END_DATE, SCHEDULE_EXPR_TIMEZONE, AUTO_TIMER, TIMEOUT_METHOD_NAME, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DECLARING_CLASS, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DESCRIPTOR, CALENDAR_TIMER FROM JBOSS_EJB_TIMER WHERE TIMED_OBJECT_ID=$1 and ID=$2 AND PARTITION_COL=$3;
create-table.hsql=CREATE TABLE JBOSS_EJB_TIMER (ID VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, TIMED_OBJECT_ID VARCHAR NOT NULL, INITIAL_DATE DATETIME, REPEAT_INTERVAL BIGINT, NEXT_DATE DATETIME, PREVIOUS_RUN DATETIME, PRIMARY_KEY VARCHAR, INFO VARCHAR, TIMER_STATE VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_SECOND VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MINUTE VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_HOUR VARCHAR,SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_WEEK VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_DAY_OF_MONTH VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_MONTH VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_YEAR VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_START_DATE VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_END_DATE VARCHAR, SCHEDULE_EXPR_TIMEZONE VARCHAR, AUTO_TIMER SMALLINT, TIMEOUT_METHOD_NAME VARCHAR, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DECLARING_CLASS VARCHAR, TIMEOUT_METHOD_DESCRIPTOR VARCHAR, CALENDAR_TIMER SMALLINT, PARTITION_COL VARCHAR NOT NULL);CREATE INDEX JBOSS_EJB_TIMER_IDENX ON JBOSS_EJB_TIMER (PARTITION_COL, TIMED_OBJECT_ID);
```

**Timer service definition in standalone-full-ha.xml**

```
<timer-service thread-pool-name="timer" default-data-store="clustered-store">
    <data-stores>
        <database-data-store name="clustered-store" datasource-jndi-name="java:/TestSybaseDB" partition="timer"/>
    </data-stores>
</timer-service>
```

I am getting the below error:

**Error**

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS014263: Cannot create table for timer persistence: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: There is already an object named 'JBOSS_EJB_TIMER' in the database.

at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.updateLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedStatement.java:375)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.persistence.database.DatabaseTimerPersistence.runCreateTable(DatabaseTimerPersistence.java:150) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.persistence.database.DatabaseTimerPersistence.start(DatabaseTimerPersistence.java:117) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
```

From the above error, I thought `create-table` in `timer-sql.properties` is causing the problem and hence, I tried removing it but getting the below error.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ejb3.timerService.timerPersistence.clustered-store: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ejb3.timerService.timerPersistence.clustered-store: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.persistence.database.DatabaseTimerPersistence.runCreateTable(DatabaseTimerPersistence.java:146)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.persistence.database.DatabaseTimerPersistence.start(DatabaseTimerPersistence.java:117)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
... 3 more

ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "ejb3"),
("service" => "timer-service"),
("database-data-store" => "clustered-store")
]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.ejb3.timerService.timerPersistence.clustered-store" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ejb3.timerService.timerPersistence.clustered-store: Failed to start service
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}

JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.ejb3.timerService.timerPersistence.clustered-store: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ejb3.timerService.timerPersistence.clustered-store: Failed to start service
```

Could anyone please help me in resolving the error and configure EJB timer service for the datasource defined in Wildfly AS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can delete the last line of timer-sql.properties file.
If the statements are working fine in the Sybase, it should work.

I've used this [article](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/creating-clustered-ejb-3-timers) and it work great for me. I'm using Postgres instead of Sybase

Comment: I am still getting "ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS014263: Cannot create table for timer persistence: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: There is already an object named 'JBOSS_EJB_TIMER' in the database.
" after removing the last line.. Marcel.

Comment: @sridhar Could you try to search for all objects with that name ? The query is something like select * from sysobjects as o where o.name like "% JBOSS_EJB_TIMER%";

Comment: Thanks for the response .. Marcel. JBOSS_EJB_TIMER table exists in the database. I also verified LOAD_TIMER sql in a separate test program to see if there are any issues but I was not getting any exception or error. The exception still happens with the server.